# Understanding window functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

Postgres-sql:

I'm not able to find a resource which can help me understand how to correctly use aggregates with/inside window functions and how to use RANGE/ROWS frame_clause correctly. I have reviewed some resources online, like:
https://www.compose.com/articles/metrics-maven-window-frames-in-postgresql/ 
(I really liked the article, it solved some doubts)

1. Using aggregates correctly with/inside window functions
   SUM() OVER(... )
   sometimes produces multiple rows when I'm least expecting them, or asks me to add more columns to groupby

For example:
For the question here: https://pgexercises.com/questions/aggregates/fachours4.html

```
select facid, total from
(select facid, sum(slots) total, RANK() OVER (order by sum(slots) desc) pos
from cd.bookings
group by facid
 ) A
where pos = 1
```

I wrote this query and it works correctly. But for this: https://pgexercises.com/questions/aggregates/rollingavg.html, I wrote this query:

```
select starttime::date, sum(slots * case when memid=0 then guestcost
                        else membercost end) over (order by starttime::date asc
                                                   range BETWEEN INTERVAL '14 day' 
                                                   PRECEDING AND 
                                                   CURRENT ROW)::decimal/15 revenue
from cd.bookings B inner join cd.facilities F
on B.facid = F.facid
where starttime >= '2012-08-01' and starttime <= '2012-08-31' 
group by starttime::date, slots, memid, guestcost, membercost
order by starttime::date
```

and it asks me to add slots, memid, guestcost, membercost to the groupby when they are a part of the average calculation.
I haven't correctly solved this question yet.

2. How do different window functions operate with RANGE/ROWS?
   For example, rank() seems to produce correct results without frame clause `UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` being specified for it, but for the last_value() calculation here, there is a need to specify this clause:

```
SELECT
    product_name,
    group_name,
    price,
    LAST_VALUE (price) OVER (
        PARTITION BY group_name
        ORDER BY
            price RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
        AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
    ) AS highest_price_per_group
FROM
    products
INNER JOIN product_groups USING (group_id);
```

(this example is taken from here: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/ - sorry, not able to select the exact area in the page to link here)

vs

```
SELECT
    RANK () OVER ( 
        ORDER BY price
    ) rank_number 
FROM
    sales;
```

-> this ranks correctly without needing to specify the `BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` clause.

Comment: Strongly suggest you keep the regular SUM separate from the analytical/window function SUM(..) OVER(), mixing them in the same SELECT is confusing (need to understand the 'logical' order of eval to see how they will influence the result). The former is to shrink rows into a single row corresponding to GROUP BY (that is why you need to list everything on the SELECT clause that is not being aggregated on the GROUP BY; each combination in the GROUP BY produces exactly one row of output).

Comment: But SUM() OVER() does not change the number of rows produced, it simply calculates the SUM requested and displays it against this row (but it can use values from the window, ie possibly other rows). As for differences on how to form partitions (windows), even rdbms products differ. Initially using them with care; and build  knowledge and confidence on your product (postgresql?)

Comment: right @tinazmu - thats what I'm learning to differentiate between. Thanks for the pointers. Yes, this is for postgres-sql

Answer (score 1):

https://momjian.us/main/writings/pgsql/window.pdf  (slide 35 and slide 36)
https://modern-sql.com/caniuse/over_range_between_(numeric)
I hope the following picture can help you understand the difference between  *over rows* versus *over range*.
[image]

Comment: I knew that `RANGE` considers ties. I didn't know that this looks at the values and not the rows, though. Thank you. This image helped me understand this. I wish that SQL would then require we write `AND CURRENT VALUE` or the like instead of `CURRENT ROW` when using `RANGE`. A pity that it doesn't, because that makes the clause misleading in my opinion.